# Session or device error occurred in file AS400/IBM i

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am learning IBM `i RPG programming` and am stuck on displaying a subfile. I keep getting the error "`Session or device error occurred in file"`. That is supposed to happen in scenarios such as trying to write more than 9999 records to the subfile and turning on `SFLDSP` indicator on empty subfile but my program has none of such problems. Can anyone help me to spot what I'm doing wrong here?

**Display file - STUDD**

```
A                                      DSPSIZ(24 80 *DS3)    
  
A          R SFLREC                    SFL                     
A            OPT$01         1Y 0B  6 10EDTCDE(Z)               
A            ID$            3Y 0B  6 25EDTCDE(3)               
A            NAME$         20   O  6 33                 
       
A          R SFLCTL                    SFLCTL(SFLREC)          
A                                      CF03(03 'EXIT')         
A                                      CF06(06 'ADD')          
A  30                                  SFLDSP                  
A  31                                  SFLDSPCTL               
A  32                                  SFLCLR                  
A  33                                  SFLEND(*MORE)           
A                                      SFLSIZ(0020)            
A                                      SFLPAG(0005)            
A                                  5 18'STUDENT ID'                        
A                                  5 33'NAME'                              
A                                  5  9'OPT'
```

**RPGLE source file - STUDR**

```
FSTUDP     IF   E           K DISK                         
FSTUDD     CF   E             WORKSTN SFILE(SFLCTL:RRN)    
                                                           
D RRN             S              4  0                      
                 
  //Clear subfile                                          
  *in32 = *on;      //SFLCLR                                         
  *in30 = *off;     //SFLDSP                                         
  write sflctl;                                            
  *in32 = *off;     //SFLCLR  
  *in31 = *on;      //SFLDSPCTL                                       
  rrn = 0;                                                   
         
  //Add one dummy record to subfile and display                                                  
  rrn += 1;                                                   
  id$ = 123;                                                   
  name$ = 'aaa';                                             
  write sflrec;     //**The said exception happens right here.                    
                   
  *in30 = *on;                                               
  exfmt sflrec;                 
                           
  *inlr = *on;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SFILE keyword refers to the subfile control, not the subfile. The error says the RRN is not valid because it does jot receive one

```
FSTUDD     CF   E             WORKSTN SFILE(SFLREC:RRN)
```

when change the subfile can't be read/exfmt you have to use the control format there

```
  exfmt sflctl;
```